# jQuery mobile change page does not reload page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using JQM 1.4.2 and have this JS:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "page.html", { reloadPage: true} );
```

and it works fine. Problem is, this will be deprecated in 1.5.0
now I try to use this:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "page.html", { reload:true } );
```

and it does not work (page is not reloaded).
How to force page to reload?
Thank you.

Comment: You will need to give us more information because new way of page changing works just fine.

Comment: Hello just use your index.html and instead of $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", "second.html" .... please use this: $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", "index.html" .... and before you click on Button, please change <h3>First Page</h3> to <h3>Something else</h3> (using notepad) and then press Button again... I expect that I see changed page content (that page is "reloaded" but it does not work. Thank you.

Comment: Look at my update section

Answer (score 2):

First are you sure you are using correct jQuery Mobile 1.4 version?  Beta versions of jQuery Mobile 1.4 didn't have pagecontainer widget.

This functionality works just fine.

I even made you a working example:

#### HTML1 - index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo 1</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
            $(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
                $(document).on('click', '#changePage', function(){ 
                    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", "second.html", { reload: "true" } );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
                <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <input type="button" value="Button" id="changePage">
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

#### HTML2 - second.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo 2</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div data-role="page" id="second" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Second Page
                </h3>
                <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

### Update:

From what I can see this is a bug. I have reported it here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7406

Comment: Leave your comment here, don't do it inside my answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks but I need to reload same page and not to open second page. I changed on your index.html that it should open same page (index.html) so when you open index.html and then when you click on "Button", please try to change page header text (using notepad) and then please click on "Button" again - I need that page is reloaded but it always show old header .. Thank you.